# Using the 'And' Operator in a For-Loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror

So I'm a bit curious about why this doesn't work.

How come code like:

```
for a in range(10) and b in range(10):
  print a + b
```

generates an error that says 'b is not defined'?

Also, code like:

```
for a,b in range(10):
  print a + b
```

generates an error: 'int objects are not iterable'.

Why? I haven't established their value beforehand, so how would Python know they are int objects? Also, I know you could use a while loop instead, but is there any way to carry out the sort of operation I'm doing using a for-loop alone?

Comment: What do you expect `a` and `b` to be?

Comment: Your attempt is parsed as `for a in (range(10) and (b in range(10))`. `b` must be defined in order to evaluate the second part of the `and` expression. (The first part, `range(10)`, will always be true since it is a non-empty list in Python 2 and a `range` object in Python 3.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for a,b in zip(range(10),range(10)):
    print a + b
```

should work great... assuming I understood your question properly 
if not then

```
for a in range(10):
    for b in range(10):
        print a+b
```

or even `[a+b for a in range(10) for b in range(10)]`

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something like the latter piece of code; provides me a great sequence of numbers I'm trying to use to answer a Project Euler problem.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers explained the right way to do it, but nobody explained what was wrong with what you did yet.

```
for a in range(10) and b in range(10):
  print a + b
```

That's a cute idea of some intuitive syntax, but Python doesn't know that one. The precedence of what you programmed actually works out like this:

```
for a in ((range(10)) and (b in range(10))):
```

Python thinks you're trying to make a complex expression to generate a *single* iterable to iterate over. The first error occurs when it tries to evaluate b to build the value. If b was defined, then `b in range(10)` would result in `True` or `False`. The result of anding it with `range(10)` will also be a boolean. Then you'd hit another error trying to iterate over a boolean.

```
for a,b in range(10):
  print a + b
```

This kind of syntax works, if the enumeration on the right contains elements that are 2-tuples. The first step in this for loop is the equivalent of trying `a,b = 0`. It tries to "unpack" the right hand side by iterating over it. But you can't iterate over a single integer. a and b are not defined yet, but the first element of range(10) is. That's the integer you can't iterate over.

Answer (score 2):

You can only iterate over a *single* iterable at a time in a `for` loop, the code in your question as it is, is invalid. I believe this is what you intended - iterating over the two ranges *simultaneously*:

```
for a, b in zip(range(10), range(10)):
    print a + b
```

The `zip` function creates a *single* iterable of 2-element tuples, taking one element from each range, and then we can unpack each element from the tuple into separate variables.

**EDIT:**

If you were trying to nest one loop inside the other, the standard way to do it would be this:

```
for a in range(10):
    for b in range(10):
        print a + b
```

But we can achieve the same effect by using [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which looks closer to what you had in mind in the first place:

```
import itertools as it
for a, b in it.product(range(10), range(10)):
    print a + b
```

Comment: Thanks very much. What I was actually trying to do was addressed by Joran Beasley, but I didn't know about the zip function. Thanks!

Comment: @Liongold oh, I see :) anyway, see my edited answer, you'll find a nice alternative at the end